# CallableStatement.getResultSet() giving null

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am executing the following code:

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
Connection con = new DB().getConnection();
ResultSet rs = null;
JSONArray jCharts = new JSONArray();
try {
      cs = con.prepareCall("{call mypackage(?,?)}");
      cs.setInt("AdminID", Integer.parseInt(AdminID));
      cs.setInt("reportid", Integer.parseInt(reportid));
      cs.execute();
      rs = cs.getResultSet();
```

`getResultSet()` is always return null

Comment: Does your stored procedure actually return anything? Run the same statement in SQL (outside of Java). You should probably also be checking the return value of `cs.execute()`.
Assuming your stored proc returns one or more cursors etc, then you should be using `cs.getObject()` not `cs.getResultSet()`.

Comment: Remove the lines `cs.execute(); rs = cs.getResultSet();` and use `rs = cs.executeQuery()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check the output of `cs.execute()` it gives you a boolean to know if the statement was ran successfully. Take it from there.

Comment: it is return  cs : SQLServerCallableStatement:33
cs.execute() : false

Comment: i have set all the parameters but on executing it is return false  
try {
   cs = con.prepareCall("{call mypackage(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
   cs.setInt("AdminID", Integer.valueOf(AdminID).intValue());
   cs.setInt("testID", Integer.parseInt(meterid));
   cs.registerOutParameter("From", Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter("To", Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.setString("Period", null);
   cs.registerOutParameter("Interval", Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.setString("All", null);
   cs.setTime("Time", null);
   cs.setInt("ReportID", Integer.parseInt(reportid));
   cs.execute();

Comment: I would suggest that you to make it work with a simple query first. Some insert statement or so. Then see if that succeeds.